# css3 not working in compatibility mode, any alternative?

Tags: html, css

quite simply I want to make an animated tile type button.
I'm not sure what the issue is (probably an outdated server) but css3 properties don't work. (I'm using ie11 so I know they should work on my browser).

below is my code, what isn't working is RGBA or transition (which I believe to be CSS3 attributes, please correct me if I'm wrong)

any help on a workaround would be greatly appreciated, I tried to use modernizr but it just completely bamboozled me.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/StyleSheet.css">
    <style>
.tile{
    height: 190px;
    width: 190px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    max-width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-size:190px 190px;
}

.caption{
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 150px 0px 0px 0px;
    height: 190px;
    width: 190px;
}
.caption:hover {
    transition: margin .5s;
    margin: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    cursor: pointer;
}

#description{
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 25px 0px 0px 0px;
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <div class="tile" style="background:url('images/tile1.jpg'); background-size:190px 190px" >
      <div class="caption" onclick="alert('test');" >
            <p>Some caption</p>
            <p id="description">Some lengthy description that may potentially overflow into two lines</p>
       </div>`enter code here`
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

edit::
as per my lower post this is actually due to compatibility mode, this will be forced on the majority of people using the site so does anyone know if a workaround?

Comment: works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/wmg7hxc4/ . Can you be clearer about what problem you're having?

Comment: This works in Firefox and Chrome. Such things are less likely to work in any version of IE, or even Edge, but I don't know why it doesn't. If it doesn't work in IE, you should always check in more modern browsers like FF or Chrome.

Comment: @Rob it does work in IE

Comment: @KWeiss Yes. I should have said, "doesn't work for you".

Comment: the background colour of caption doesn't apply (if I set to rgb(0,0,0) then it displays fine) and the animation doesn't work, it just appears on hover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Regarding Transparency**

The transparency via the `background: rbga(...)` property appears to be working [just as expected in Internet Explorer 11](http://jsbin.com/hefuduyelo/1/edit) per your example:

[image]

Another option would be to use the CSS [`opacity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity) property, which functions similar to your use-case, however it just handles the transparency level. It does functiona a bit differently however as it is applied to the targeted element and all children of the element, so it isn't always the most appropriate choice.

```
opacity: 0.4;
```

**If the transition is the issue...**

If you want the transition to appear when you hover out of the element, you'll also need the [`transition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) property on your non-hover selector as well :

```
.caption{
   /* Other properties omitted for brevity */
   transition: margin .5s;
}
```

which can be demonstrated below:

[image]

Is there something that you are expecting to occur that isn't?

Comment: thanks for your replies, I know the transition and opacity works as expected as I've tried it myself on jsfiddle and the code seems right, I'm not sure if its a server issue that could be causing this (it is very old) . so need to try alternatives to transition and rgba. @Rion would applying "opacity:" not affect the whole div?

Comment: Is there any chance that your version of Internet Explorer is running in any type of compatibility mode? This would easily explain most of the issues that you are experiencing (as older versions or Quirks mode may not support these newer features). I would certainly consider checking that out using the Developer Tools (F12) within IE. And `opacity` would actually affect all of the children elements beneath the one is it targeting, so if you are applying to a single element the `background: rgba()` approach is preferred.

Comment: well like I said it isn't my browser, as it does work in jsfiddle and on other sites. I really don't know what the cause would be :/

Comment: And you don't have any other styles that could possibly conflict with it? Have you used the Developer Tools (F12) within your browser to inspect the elements and ensure that the styles are being applied properly?

Comment: I've removed the linked style sheet and still no dice. as I said I'm almost certain its an issue caused by the server it's hosted on. Is there a way you know of that I can implement the animation using jquery without replicating the code for each tile I add? for the opacity issue I'll just use a semi-transparent .png as a background

Comment: right I've just checked and my browser (a heavily modified one due to the company I work for) does force compatibility mode for intranet sites, hence the issues. I disabled it and presto, all works as intended